# Changing box-shadow of css using javascript on scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, scroll, box-shadow

my css of my bootstrap nav is as follows

```
.navbar-default
 {
    background-color: #fff;
    box-shadow: 5px -149px 90px 200px rgba(255,255,255,1);
    border-color: #fff;
    height:0px;
    padding: 0px;
    border: 0px;
}
```

and in my js file i am calling this function using jquery

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
    var wScroll = $(this).scrollTop();

    if (wScroll==500)
    { 
        $('.navbar-default').attr("box-shadow","5px -49px 190px 220px rgba(255,255,255,1)");
    }
    console.log(wScroll);
});
```

what i want is to change my box-shadow after scrolling about 500px but it is not happening 
help me with this please?

Comment: What if you change the condition `if (wScroll==500)` to `if (wScroll >= 500)` ?

Comment: that helped thanks and also in attr it was  :                                            attr("box-shadow",5px -49px 190px 220px rgba(255,255,255,1));

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `if (wScroll==500)`  to `if (wScroll>=500)`

and `$('.navbar-default').attr` to `$('.navbar-default').css`.

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
        var wScroll = $(this).scrollTop();

        if (wScroll>=500)
        { 
            $('.navbar-default').css("box-shadow","5px -49px 190px 220px rgba(255,255,255,1)");
        }
    });
```

**Edit:** For ease effect use trasition:

```
.navbar-default {
  transition: ease .5s;
 -webkit-transition: ease .5s;
}
```

Comment: thanks it worked can u suugest how to make it slow, right now it is just drops suddenly

Comment: Just add `transition` to your element. Im edit my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try this [sample](https://jsfiddle.net/leonardoaraujocosta/pjzmxfd5/)

```js
$('.navbar-default').css("box-shadow", "rgb(121, 122, 195) 0px 5px 5px 5px")
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-12">
      <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
        <div class="container-fluid">
          <div class="navbar-header">
            <a href="#" class="navbar-brand"> <img alt="Brand" height="20" src="data:image/png;base64,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"
              width="20"> </a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </nav>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I hope to have helped in some way